# How to clear or remove io::stdin buffer in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've been coding a simple text based game in Rust after beginning to learn the language and I've tried to implement a function to wait for the user to press enter before continuing the program.

So far after some experimentation I've gotten to this:

```
pub fn wait() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let wait_string = &mut String::new();

    wait_string.clear();
    println!("\nPress Enter to Continue\n");
    io::stdout().clear();
    stdin.read_line(wait_string);
}
```

However, my problem is that due to the hardcoded buffer on stdin the function will automatically continue without waiting if the user had pressed enter before the message had been displayed.

Is there a solution to this? Or would another approach using std::thread::sleep be better?
Apologies if this is easily solved or impossible, I'm still finding my footing in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch temporarily to non-blocking operations on the underlying file-descriptor in order to consume everything that could have been entered before this `wait()` call, and then switch back to blocking operations to actually wait for an input.

This example requires the [`libc` crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc) and only works on Unix (I guess something similar could be done on Windows with the [`winapi` crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi)).

```rust
pub fn change_blocking_fd(
    fd: std::os::unix::io::RawFd,
    blocking: bool,
) {
    unsafe {
        let flags = libc::fcntl(fd, libc::F_GETFL);
        libc::fcntl(
            fd,
            libc::F_SETFL,
            if blocking {
                flags & !libc::O_NONBLOCK
            } else {
                flags | libc::O_NONBLOCK
            },
        );
    }
}

pub fn wait() {
    use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    change_blocking_fd(stdin.as_raw_fd(), false);
    let mut wait_string = String::new();
    while stdin.read_line(&mut wait_string).is_ok_and(|n_bytes| n_bytes > 0) {
        println!("discard: {:?}", wait_string); // debug purpose only
        wait_string.clear();
    }
    change_blocking_fd(stdin.as_raw_fd(), true);
    println!("\nPress Enter to Continue\n");
    stdin.read_line(&mut wait_string).expect("!!!");
}

fn main() {
    println!("enter a few lines during five seconds");
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(5000));
    println!("~~~~ before wait() ~~~~");
    wait();
    println!("~~~~ after wait() ~~~~");
}
/*
enter a few lines during five seconds
aaa
zzz
eee
~~~~ before wait() ~~~~
discard: "aaa\n"
discard: "zzz\n"
discard: "eee\n"

Press Enter to Continue


~~~~ after wait() ~~~~
*/
```